# how to Convert a String with 22 length to an integer in java

Tags: java, sockets, hex

i want to send data via sockets and my device don`t get strings so i have to convert my string to int how i have to do it?

i have an string up to 22 chars and i must send it via sockets as integer or long or anything in numbers format but any data type in java cannot hold more than 8 bytes what should i do?

i also tried these codes :

```java
long l = Long.valueOf(message, 16);// message="11EE0000AA0000FF03A901"

long l = Long.parseLong(message, 16);// message="11EE0000AA0000FF03A901"

int l = Integer.parseInt(message, 16);// message="11EE0000AA0000FF03A901"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BigInteger val = new BigInteger(message, 16);
System.out.println(val);
```

Try this !

Answer (score 1):

Even long can't handle that 22 char Hax value. 22 char long hax value need atleast 84 bits to represent. [image]

As your client can only receive integer and each integer is 32 bit long. you can partition it into 3 different integer and send them via socket. In client side receive these 3 integer and convert/glued them to make your desired string.

Comment: yeah but a i have another problem and its this that i cant divide my integer it must be 1 number

Comment: Integer can only hold 32 bit binary data, how you will store 84 bits into a 32 bit Int type. Simply you can send that `22` char string, just using a single integer. It would be better if you add more code how you are sending and receiving data..

Comment: i just use sockets to send my data simply i don`t have any problem on sending just this one is so bad i stock on this for more than 2 month

Comment: @Mir.EbrahimJafarpourZonuzi then please show the actual code you are stuck on.